# How to retrieve database line that matches two different sets of coordinates? I.E: pickup and delivery

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy-2

When I run this query over my database, it returns every object with these coordinates.

coordinates being used in this first case: (41.8350653, -87.8630829)

```sql
SELECT 
  ... 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      ...
      AND ST_DWithin(
        p.coords, 
        ST_GeomFromWKB(
          : ST_GeomFromWKB_1, : ST_GeomFromWKB_2
        ), 
        : ST_DWithin_1
      ) 
      AND l.origin_id = p.id 
    GROUP BY 
      c.id
  ) AS anon_1
```

when I try to run a similar query with an AND operator adding one more set of coordinates, it returns nothing (even when I guarantee that the coordinates are matching the ones on the database

coordinates being used in this first case: (41.8350653, -87.8630829) and (46.733107, -59.927493)

```sql
SELECT 
  ... FROM (
    SELECT 
      AND ST_DWithin(
        p.coords, 
        ST_GeomFromWKB(
          : ST_GeomFromWKB_1, : ST_GeomFromWKB_2
        ), 
        : ST_DWithin_1
      ) 
      AND l.origin_id = p.id 
      AND ST_DWithin(
        p.coords, 
        ST_GeomFromWKB(
          : ST_GeomFromWKB_3, : ST_GeomFromWKB_4
        ), 
        : ST_DWithin_2
      ) 
      AND l.destination_id = p.id 
    GROUP BY 
      c.id
  ) AS anon_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN lane AS lane_1 ON lane_1.id = anon_1.lane_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN place AS place_1 ON place_1.id = lane_1.origin_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN place AS place_2 ON place_2.id = lane_1.destination_id
```

I'm using geoalchemy2 on PostGIS database and these queries were extracted from the code

How should I make this query return the result that has both coordinates?

EDIT:

As requested by @Kasper, some samples of my current database

This is the database structure I currently have (I'm building something like a House Moving Company)

This table represents the **Truck**, that has a key to the lane

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| uuid | uuid |
| updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
| created_at | timestamp without time zone |
| lane_id | integer |

---

This is the **Lane** table. This table represents the relationship between the truck and the lanes the truck can move. It has the origin_id and the destination_id, which is the location itself.

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| uuid | uuid |
| updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
| created_at | timestamp without time zone |
| id | integer |
| origin_id | integer |
| destination_id | integer |

---

This is the table **Place**, where we have the coords I'm trying to query

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| uuid | uuid |
| updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
| created_at | timestamp without time zone |
| id | integer |
| coords | geography(Point,4326) |

---

What I'm having trouble with is getting a **Truck** that has an origin **Place** on a specific coords and, at the same time, a destination **Place** (different from the origin one) that has some specific coords.

I think this case can be well represented by the following sentence:

"I want to know a Truck leaving NY and delivering in Chicago"

Comment: Hello, you should probably add an example of your table structure & data and which table you refer to in your sample queries to make it easier to understand them.

Comment: how can a single point have multiple coordinates? That is what the query is looking for. Either you want multiple records or you want to query different geometry columns.

Comment: @JGH That's exactly what I need. Find a way to return multiple records according to their coords, but respecting whether they are origin or destination (as the updated table structure)

Comment: @Kasper updated the question, thanks :)

Comment: you would have to join the `place` table twice

Comment: @JGH I'm kind of doing the joins already, I just didn´t put on the query but it is updated now. Sorry for the edits with the details, the data are sensitive and I must be careful about what I'm using here